# Merging two String Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to merge two independently sorted arrays to produce a single array, sorted in ascending order. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static String [] mergeStrings(String [] x, String [] y) {
    String[] result = new String[x.length + y.length];
    int largest = (x.length > y.length) ? x.length : y.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < largest; i++){

    }
}
```

Any direction from here would be wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: You'll need some kind of binary search/sort algorithm to determine the index of the best location to place each element into the new array, assuming you don't want to simply append one array to another and sort the result...

Comment: What have you tried?  (The above does not constitute trying anything, it's just screwing around to look busy.)

Comment: Hint:  Have a "next item" index for each array, initially zero.  Look at the next item of each array, compare, choose the "smallest" (using whatever your sort criteria are), then bump the index of that array.  I leave it to you to figure out the boundary conditions.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Untrue!

Comment: I would create a result array, take the biggest of the 2 input array and array copy into result then [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or use a suitable java collection

Comment: @RC. -You can do it in O(N+M) time -- no sort of any type needed.

Comment: @RC if the 2 source arrays are sorted, your implementation is not optimal.

Comment: Plus it's not what the instructor wants.

Comment: @HotLicks "compare, choose the "smallest"" sounds like a sort to me.

Comment: @RC. - See an audiologist.

Comment: @RC. read the question content one more time: *I am trying to merge **two independently sorted arrays** to produce a single array, **sorted** in ascending order*.

Comment: If you do that: *add the contents of one at the end, then merge* (from your deleted comment), you have failed to accomplish the homework exercise

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Because what you said is demonstrably wrong -- there is no need for "some kind of binary search/sort algorithm".

Comment: @HotLicks It's a way to achieve the result, without using inbuilt functionality, assuming the lists are unequal ;)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < x.length || j < y.length; k++){
    if (j==y.length || (i!=x.length && x[i].compareTo(y[j]) <= 0)
        result[k] = x[i++];
    else
        result[k] = y[j++];
}
```

Comment: While this is what OP's teacher wants the students to achieve, it is not right from us to give a straight answer to homework problems.

Comment: -1 Yes, this is the right answer, but it's not right to answer a homework question with actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the merge to prune duplicates as well

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeStrings( // "5" repeats
        new String[] {"1", "5", "8"}, new String[] {"2", "5", "6", "9"})));

public static String [] mergeStrings(String [] x, String [] y) {
    List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int xp = 0, yp = 0;
    while ( xp < x.length && yp < y.length){
        if (x[xp].compareTo(y[yp]) < 0) {
            mergedList.add(x[xp++]);
        } else if (x[xp].compareTo(y[yp]) > 0) {
            mergedList.add(y[yp++]);
        } else {
            mergedList.add(x[xp]);
            xp++; yp++;
        }
    }
    while (xp < x.length) {
        mergedList.add(x[xp++]);
    }
    while (yp < y.length) {
        mergedList.add(y[yp++]);
    }
    return mergedList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

***Output** :*

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

See comments below.

```
public static String [] mergeStrings(String [] x, String [] y) {
    //You declared the array that has enough size to wraph both x and y arrays. Good.
    String[] result = new String[x.length + y.length];

    // get the size of the bigger array?
    int largest = (x.length > y.length) ? x.length : y.length; 

    //If x.length is bigger, this will iterate x.length times, y.length otherwise.. 
    for (int i = 0; i < largest; i++){ 
    //even if you used result[i]=x[i] you would be missing elements for y. 
    }
}
```

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
  public static String[] mergeStrings(String[] x, String[] y) {
    //Declare the result string with the sum of sizes.
    String[] result = new String[x.length + y.length];
    //Assign `x` values to result.
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      result[i] = x[i];
    }

    //Assign `y` values to result. Using resultIndex to start on the first empty position while `i` will be the index for the `y` array.
    for (int i = 0, resultIndex = x.length; i < y.length; i++, resultIndex++) {
      result[resultIndex] = y[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
```